# What kind of printmaking produces a faded result like a stamp?

Tags: print-design, print-production, screen-printing

What kind of printmaking produces results like this?  It looks almost like a stamp.

[image]

Another print with similar aesthetics is here, especially pay attention how the lower end fades out.

[image]

Comment: Side note: For the Instagram image you linked you can get the full resolution version by viewing the source code and searching for "og:image" to get [this](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/18299522_214907915674947_6430400206365261824_n.jpg).

Comment: If I am not very much deceived I can see the stamp embossing in the first image.

Comment: [Flexography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexography) can look very similar to a stamp because it is essentially the same process. I would be willing to lay decent odds that the print in your second image was produced with this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The effects that you are referencing are actually the result of printing errors / bad printing.

The 'Postkarte' image shows signs of under inking. This was probably produced with a rubber stamp and the effect in the image is caused by the fact that the stamp is running low on ink, most likely because it has already been used to produce several impressions without being re-inked.

The other image that you link is a different issue. This is the result of printing ink on a nonporous surface. Either the stamp (if that's what was used) has slipped against the surface when it was applied or the ink has stayed wet and then been smudged / smeared by something that touched it before it was dry.

Both examples are also considered relief printmaking, which means that ink is spread on the surface of an object and then pressed into the paper. Like a stamp.

This contrasts with other methods of printmaking such as intaglio (wiping ink into crevices and then achieving a print with high pressure) or serigraphy/screenprinting (pushing ink through a membrane, which is selectively blocked). Similar over- or under-inking in these methods would produce a different result.

Comment: There is a chance that the first image is the old normal typography print (with metal letters), because it has a slight inverted emboss look, like there is a shadow on the top side.

Comment: @Rafael: I think the dark edges in the first image are not shadows but just more ink being deposited there, which is something I've seen happening with rubber stamps.

Answer (score 1):

maybe hot stamping. check shiny stamps also.

Comment: No, not hotstamping, because there are not traces of film.